# Update nested field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I can't update my object within nested object field. In here I can't update `name` from Movie model. Here is my model.py:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=800, unique=True)
    imdb_rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    movie_choice = (
        ('Act', 'Action'),
      ...........
    )
    movie_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=movie_choice)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Hiren(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
    watched_full = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    source = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    watched_at = models.DateField()
    quality_choice = (
  ..................
    )
    video_quality = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=quality_choice)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

and serializer.py

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = '__all__'


class HirenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movie = MovieSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Hiren
        fields = ('movie', 'id', 'watched_full', 'rating', 'source', 'video_quality', 'watched_at')


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.movie.name = validated_data.get('movie.name', instance.movie.name)
        instance.watched_full = validated_data.get('watched_full', instance.watched_full)
        instance.rating = validated_data.get('rating', instance.rating)
        instance.source = validated_data.get('source', instance.source)
        instance.video_quality = validated_data.get('video_quality', instance.video_quality)
        instance.watched_at = validated_data.get('watched_at', instance.watched_at)
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call `save` on related object

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.movie.name = validated_data.get('movie', {}).get('name') or instance.movie.name 
    instance.watched_full = validated_data.get('watched_full', instance.watched_full)
    instance.rating = validated_data.get('rating', instance.rating)
    instance.source = validated_data.get('source', instance.source)
    instance.video_quality = validated_data.get('video_quality', instance.video_quality)
    instance.watched_at = validated_data.get('watched_at', instance.watched_at)
    # here
    instance.movie.save()
    instance.save()

    return instance
```

Comment: still I got same problem

Comment: @pyprism print `validated_data.get('movie.name', instance.movie.name)` and see if you actually getting correct data from this. May be you just setting default value

Comment: @pyprism try `validated_data.get('movie', {}).get('name') or instance.movie.name`